# What could be some applications of Chaos Theory in Computer Science?

Tags: computer-science, chaos-theory

I am a Computer Science student. While going through some random maths topics I came across Chaos Theory. I wanted to know if there are any applications of it in CS.
I tried searching on the internet about this but ended up only with [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31000/does-chaos-theory-have-any-practical-application-in-computer-security) and [this](http://www.slideshare.net/konakid/computer-science-student-uses-chaos-theory-to-create-new-routes).
But are there any other domains of computer science where this theory could be applied ?

Please help!

Answer (score 6):

1. A small world network introduced with time delay generates chaos. Databases that are linked in a small world network are faster to extract information from. Most neural networks are small world networks.
2. Computer graphics? Generating realistic-looking animations of flames, flowing water etc. involves mimicing the chaotic processes that form them.

Comment: The concept of Small World Networks looks interesting. Could you please elaborate on it or give any reference to it so that I could do more research on it?

Comment: Related links: [http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/~myers/teaching/ComputationalMethods/ComputerExercises/SmallWorld/SmallWorld.html], [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_world_networks#cite_note-16]

Answer (score 4):

Cryptography is another application of chaos to computer science. There are a few chaotic encryption schemes around.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most fascinating account of chaos in computer science I have read comes when you analyze the attempted solutions to NP problems.

Here's a link that explains how the "hardness" of a Sudoku is related to chaotic behavior of solutions
http://www.nature.com/srep/2012/121011/srep00725/full/srep00725.html