# Project ideas on Chaos theory, Cellular Automata, Fractals, Games, IA

Tags: soft-question, fractals, chaos-theory, artificial-intelligence, cellular-automata

I'm a computer science student and I need to find a final year project. What interests me the most is Chaos, IA, Games, Fractals, CA.. 
Something I liked was [the chaos theory within sudoku](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep00725).

The question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424209/what-could-be-some-applications-of-chaos-theory-in-computer-science?rq=1) but it is 5 year old and so there is surely new interesting topics.

Feel free to submit ideas, even crazy ones! (Maybe an unconsidered link between 2 separate domains that have surprising results)